# Topology on a sigma-algebra

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I was thinking about how to define the support of a (positive) measure $\mu$ on $(X,\Sigma)$. In order to mimic the standard definition for that of functions, I'm tempted to define something like
$$\text{spt}\mu= \bigcap_{A}\overline{\{A\in \Sigma: \mu(A)>0\}}.$$
To make this definition go through, we need a topology on the sigma algebra $\Sigma$. So suppose $X$ is a topological space, then one can put various topologies on its power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ which is canonically isomorphic to $f:X\to T$ where $T$ is a two point space. If we equip $T$ with a topology (I'm not sure which one, but probably discrete), the typical induced topology on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the compact-open topology, which in turn induces a topology on $\Sigma\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$. So through this abstract prescription, a topology on $X$ induces a topology on (for example), its Borel sigma algebra $\Sigma=\mathcal{B}(X)$. The "standard" definition of the support of a Boreal measure $\mu$ is defined as
$$\text{spt}\mu=\bigcap_{C \text{ closed}} \{C:\mu(X-C)=0\}.$$
My question is are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Union is definitely wrong here, if $\mu(X) > 0$ then $\text{spt}\ \mu = X$ in that case

Comment: I suggest $\text{spt}\ \mu := \bigcap \overline{\{A\in \Sigma : \mu(A) > 0\}}$ as a potential candidate.

Comment: Ok great, let’s go with that. But I guess in such case we don’t need a topology on $\Sigma$ anymore, since the closure in happening in X.

Comment: If the closure in the first definition is in $\Sigma$ (where else would it be?) then it produces a subset of $\Sigma$, so in what sense would the two definitions be equivalent?